# What's the layouts folder for in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I understand that .html.erb files go within `app/views` or its subfolders. But what is the `app/views/layouts` folder in particular for in Rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`app/views/layouts` is the folder in which rails looks for the `layouts`.

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts :

> To find the current layout, Rails first looks for a file in
>   app/views/layouts with the same base name as the controller. For
>   example, rendering actions from the PhotosController class will use
>   app/views/layouts/photos.html.erb (or
>   app/views/layouts/photos.builder). If there is no such
>   controller-specific layout, Rails will use
>   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb or
>   app/views/layouts/application.builder. If there is no .erb layout,
>   Rails will use a .builder layout if one exists. Rails also provides
>   several ways to more precisely assign specific layouts to individual
>   controllers and actions.

**What is a layout?**

A layout defines the surroundings of an HTML page. It's the place to define common look and feel of the page.

The RailsCasts episode - [All About Layouts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/7-all-about-layouts?view=asciicast) - though very old, is still very useful in this context.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on the meaning of the term "layout" itself.

Answer (score 0):

Layout in rails framework is very important folder, main layout of your application is define here as `application.html.erb` and all the views are yielded here using <% yield %>